# Gcc version of python used within anaconda

Tags: python, conda

How do I change the gcc version of python used within anaconda or a virtual environment?
Right now when I start python it shows:

```
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

on linux2
This is the same as the system-wide `gcc` in `/usr/bin/`
However, I want it to use the version `/etc/scl/prefixes/devtoolset-2:`
which is `gcc 4.8`

Many thanks.

Comment: What does `which python` say?  And `which gcc`?

Comment: 1) You should use the same gcc version your glibc and other libraries have been built with. 2) `/etc` is definitively the wrong place to install external files, expecially binaries! That's what `/opt`, resp. `/user/local` are for.

Answer (score 6):

Python shows you the compiler and version that *was used to build python*, it doesn't use this at runtime. The version of GCC used to build python doesn't matter itself.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's the correct answer, just the wording could be better.